# Saving System.Drawing.Graphics to a png or bmp

Tags: c#, graphics

I have a Graphics object that I've drawn on the screen and I need to save it to a png or bmp file.  Graphics doesn't seem to support that directly, but it must be possible somehow.

What are the steps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copy it to a `Bitmap` and then call the bitmap's `Save` method.

Note that if you're *literally* drawing to the screen (by grabbing the screen's device context), then the only way to save what you just drew to the screen is to reverse the process by drawing *from* the screen *to* a `Bitmap`.  This is possible, but it would obviously be a lot easier to just draw directly to a Bitmap (using the same code you use to draw to the screen).

Comment: For future readers:  despite the title of this question, this answer doesn't show how to save an arbitrary Graphics object to an image. That is, there is no function in either Graphics or Bitmap that does "Copy it (the Graphics instance) to a Bitmap".  From the last sentence, it is probably referring to doing `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)`, and then rendering to **that** graphics (g), instead of to your original graphics object.  Then you can do bitmap.Save to save what you have rendered.

Answer (score 31):

Here is the code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(1024), Convert.ToInt32(1024), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

// Add drawing commands here
g.Clear(Color.Green);

bitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\johndoe\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

If your Graphics is on a form, you can use this:

```
private void DrawImagePointF(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   ... Above code goes here ...

   e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
}
```

In addition, to save on a web page, you could use this:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
var pngData = memoryStream.ToArray();

<img src="data:image/png;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(pngData))"/>
```

Graphics objects are a GDI+ drawing surface. They must have an attached device context to draw on ie either a form or an image.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, which is to take a GRAPHICS object, and copy that into a bitmap.  This code seems to do the OPPOSITE.  (I have a situation where a "Graphics" is being passed to a method, and the source of the "Graphics" is not accessible at that place in the code, only the "Graphics" itself.)

Answer (score 6):

Try this, works fine for me...

```
private void SaveControlImage(Control ctr)
{
    try
    {
        var imagePath = @"C:\Image.png";

        Image bmp = new Bitmap(ctr.Width, ctr.Height);
        var gg = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        var rect = ctr.RectangleToScreen(ctr.ClientRectangle);
        gg.CopyFromScreen(rect.Location, Point.Empty, ctr.Size);

        bmp.Save(imagePath);
        Process.Start(imagePath);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that actually create a PNG file though? That looks like you are just saving a bitmap to a file with PNG extension?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely drawing either to an image or on a control. If on image use

```
    Image.Save("myfile.png",ImageFormat.Png)
```

If drawing on control use Control.DrawToBitmap() and then save the returned image as above.

Thanks for the correction - I wasn't aware you can draw directly to the screen.

Comment: You *can* draw directly to the screen using Graphics, which has a constructor that takes a device context - all you need is the screen's device context.

Comment: Thanks for this, it has never occurred to me to try drawing straight to the screen!

Comment: I would actually recommend *not* drawing directly to the screen, since there's really no point to doing so.

Answer (score 1):

```
Graphics graph = CreateGraphics();
Bitmap bmpPicture = new Bitmap("filename.bmp");

graph.DrawImage(bmpPicture, width, height);
```