# Issue capturing windows form drawing to image C#

Tags: c#, image, save, drawing

I'm trying to draw a few objects to a windows form, then create a image of that form and save it to a folder.

This is a two part question... Why isn't the image that is being drawn to the windows form showing up on the created image? Also second question is, how can I create an image of the windows form drawing, from say point 0,0 to point 500,500 **without** a background....

Here is the code I have at the moment....

```
Form draw = new Drawing();      // Opens the drawing form
draw.Show();

        try
        {
            //Try to draw something...
            System.Drawing.Pen myPen;       
            myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = draw.CreateGraphics();
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            myPen.Dispose();
            formGraphics.Dispose();

            var path = this.outputFolder.Text;      // Create variable with output path

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);  // Create path if it doesn't exist
            }

            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(draw.Width, draw.Height))  // Creating the .bmp file from windows form
            {
                draw.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
                bitmap.Save(path + "\\" + i + ".bmp");
             }
        }
        catch { }
```

Can you see anything wrong here? What seems to be prohibiting the drawings to be saved to a .bmp file?

Thank in advance!

Comment: your bitmap is the size of the form, but otherwise has nothing to do with the form;  also not sure what the first part has to do with anything; CreateGraphics is almost always the wrong way to draw something to a form

Comment: What do you mean, the first part has nothing to do with anything... can you elaborate? How do you suggest I draw something to a form, bearing in mind it needs to be saved as an image later.

Comment: the stuff *you draw* to the form *you* also have to draw to the bitmap; the form is not a canvas which will retain what is drawn to it elsewhere.  if you dont want a background (does that mean the form backcolor?) then set use MakeTransparent to set it so - any controls with that color will also be white/uncolored in the image.  you'd also probably have to save as PNG to save the transparency

Comment: Ok, well lets say, I didn't really need to draw the image to a form... is there a way to use a control similar to CreateGraphics, to draw directly to a .bmp or .png?

Comment: I used examples from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928845/saving-system-drawing-graphics-to-a-png-or-bmp Seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the example shown here [Saving System.Drawing.Graphics to a png or bmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928845/saving-system-drawing-graphics-to-a-png-or-bmp)

```
        Form draw = new Drawing();      // Opens the drawing form
        draw.Show();
        try
        {
            var path = this.outputFolder.Text; // Path where images will be saved to

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);     // Create a directory if it does not already exist
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(1024), Convert.ToInt32(1024), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

            System.Drawing.Pen myPen;
            myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            g.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 0, 1024, 1024);

            bitmap.Save(path + "\\" + i + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);

        }
        catch { }
```

And that has worked flawlessly for me now :D