# How to save severel image(.png,.jpg) file in same folder without SavefileDialog in C#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a snapshot application in C# and I want it to save the snapshots without SaveFileDilog.I'v used a timer.
Means when timer will stop  there will be no prompt to save the file,it will do that in background.
and thanks in advance:)
code is

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics GH = Graphics.FromImage(Form1.bm as Image);
        GH.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Form1.bm.Size);
        this.pic_box.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pic_box.Image = Form1.bm;
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        SaveFileDialog SFD = new SaveFileDialog();
        SFD.Filter = "Image File | *.PNG";
        SFD.DefaultExt = ".png";
        SFD.FileName = "cap(#).png";
        if (SFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Form1.bm.Save(SFD.FileName);
            MessageBox.Show("Saved", "Saved successfully", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving System.Drawing.Graphics to a png or bmp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928845/saving-system-drawing-graphics-to-a-png-or-bmp)

Comment: Sorry but It is not the code I want,
I want to save with out prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the SaveFileDialog then:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics GH = Graphics.FromImage(Form1.bm as Image);
    GH.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Form1.bm.Size);
    this.pic_box.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pic_box.Image = Form1.bm;
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    Form1.bm.Save("cap(#).png");
    this.Close();
}
```